# How can I delare this in Array

Tags: vbscript

this is the example.
what if the array should be from Mynum1="1" to MyNum100="100"

> MyNum1="1"
>
> MyNum2="2"
>
> MyNum3="3"

wat is the best way to declare this.

Answer (score 2):

To iterate through a 100 of these:

```
Dim myNum(99)

for i = 0 to 99
    myNum(i) = i+1
next

for i = 0 to 99
    wscript.echo i & " - " & myNum(i)
next
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but look at the variables.. MyNum1="1", MyNum2="2".... see the difference?? that really is my problem...

Comment: Can you explain why this solution will not work for you? Arrays are the solution to this kind of problem. MyNum1 is the same as myNum(1).

Comment: @ServerGuy `MyNum1` is certainly different from `myNum(1)`.

Comment: @NormanPaul You can convert the integers like 1, 2, 42 to strings by using the 'convert to string' function: `MyVar = CStr(23)`. Now `MyVar` contains the string literal `"23"`.

Answer (score 1):

Declare it as an `Array`:

```
MyNums = Array("1", "2", "3")
```

You can access each one with:

```
foo = MyNums(1)
```

Which will assign `foo` to `"2"`.

Comment: Old habits die hard. It's gone. :)

Answer (score 1):

Technically it is feasible, but it is a very bad practice. You can execute code that is created on the fly with the `Execute` statement:

```
Dim i
for i = 1 to 100
    Execute "Dim myNum" & i & " : myNum" & i & " = """ & i & """"
     ' Creates and executes strings like: Dim myNum1 : myNum1 = "1"
next
```

Again, don't do this if there is any other way, like the use of an array as DesertIvy and ServerGuy showed you.

Comment: Fancy that - Didn't know that was possible.